# ShinyTree in ShinyDashboard sidebar

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinytree, shinydashboardplus

I have a nice dynamically produced shinyTree that displays beautifully in the main body of a shinydashboard. Which is wonderful. However, what I actually want is for it to be in the sidebar so it can be used to select a tab. But no matter what I try, I cant seem to get it to appear in the sidebar.

Not working code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTree)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "MWE")
body <- dashboardBody(
  # works fine in the body
  shinyTree("tree", stripes = TRUE, multiple = FALSE, animation = FALSE)
)
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  # doesn't work here
  # shinyTree("tree", stripes = TRUE, multiple = FALSE, animation = FALSE)
  sidebarMenu(
    # doesn't work here
    # shinyTree("tree", stripes = TRUE, multiple = FALSE, animation = FALSE)
    menuItem("test"
         # or here
         # shinyTree("tree", stripes = TRUE, multiple = FALSE, animation = FALSE)
    )
  )
)

shinyUI(
  dashboardPage(
   header = header,
   sidebar = sidebar,
   body = body
  )
)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  # Simplified test tree
  output$tree <- renderTree({
    list(
      root1 = "",
      root2 = list(
        SubListA = list(leaf1 = "", leaf2 = "", leaf3=""),
        SubListB = list(leafA = "", leafB = "")
      ),
      root3 = list(
        SubListA = list(leaf1 = "", leaf2 = "", leaf3=""),
        SubListB = list(leafA = "", leafB = "")
      )
    )
  })
})
```

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious, but my searching on google and here hasn't brought anything up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm an idiot. Apparently you can only have a single instance of a shinyTree, so the shihyTree in the body was preventing the shinyTree in the sidebar show up.

Working code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTree)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "MWE")
body <- dashboardBody(
    # Don't put the shinyTree in the body!
    # shinyTree("tree", stripes = TRUE, multiple = FALSE, animation = FALSE)
)
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
    #shinyTree("tree", stripes = TRUE, multiple = FALSE, animation = FALSE),
    sidebarMenu(
        shinyTree("tree", stripes = TRUE, multiple = FALSE, animation = FALSE)
    )
)


ui <-   dashboardPage(
        header = header,
        sidebar = sidebar,
        body = body
    )


server <- function(input, output, session) {
    # Simplified test tree
    output$tree <- renderTree({
        list(
            root1 = "",
            root2 = list(
                SubListA = list(leaf1 = "", leaf2 = "", leaf3=""),
                SubListB = list(leafA = "", leafB = "")
            ),
            root3 = list(
                SubListA = list(leaf1 = "", leaf2 = "", leaf3=""),
                SubListB = list(leafA = "", leafB = "")
            )
        )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```